# Rewrite Endpoint Url without ? before endpoint

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, endpoints

Created Custom Post type called members, don't need a members permalink, but need to link to member patents, if exists for member (which I got figured out).

The problem I'm facing is the creation of the `ep_mask` and rewrites for the endpoint here.

Basically, I create a member named, "John Doe", now want the url to be something like this for showing his patents:

/member/john-doe/patents

but I have something like this now:  member/john-doe/?patents

How do I get rid of the `?` mark in the url?

```
register_post_type('team_member', array(
        'description'           => __('Team Members'),
        'label'                 => __('team_members'),
        'labels'                => array(
            'name'                  => _x('Team Member', 'Post Type General Name'),
            'singular_name'         => _x('Team Member', 'Post Type Singular Name'),
            'menu_name'             => __('Team Members'),
            'parent_item_colon'     => __('Parent Team Member'),
            'all_items'             => __('All Team Members'),
            'view_item'             => __('View Team Member'),
            'add_new_item'          => __('Add New Team Member'),
            'add_new'               => __('Add New'),
            'edit_item'             => __('Edit Team Member'),
            'update_item'           => __('Update Team Member'),
            'search_items'          => __('Search Team Members'),
            'not_found'             => __('Not Found'),
            'not_found_in_trash'    => __('Not Found in Trash')
        ),
        'taxonomies'            => array('department', 'team'),
        'supports'              => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
        'rewrite'               => array('slug' => 'member', 'ep_mask' => 'patents'),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => false,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => false,
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'query_var'             => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => false,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'page'
    )
);



add_filter( 'request', 'filter_request' );
function filter_request($vars)
{
    if(isset($vars['patents']))
        $vars['patents'] = true;

    return $vars;
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'catch_vars' );
function catch_vars()
{
    global $wp_query;

    if (!isset($wp_query->query_vars['patents']) || !is_singular())
        return;

    // Template here for Member Specific Patents!
    include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/single-team_member-patents.php');
    exit;
}
```

How to make the endpoint a folder structure instead of a `?` at end with query string?

**EDIT**

I am using this within the `init` action also:

```
function do_stuff() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint('patents', EP_PERMALINK);
}
add_action('init', 'do_stuff');
```

Comment: `patents` isn't a valid value for `ep_mask`, endpoint masks are defined in the rewrite API and listed on the [`add_rewrite_endpoint` codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint).

Comment: How do you add another sub-level url, in this case `/patents/` for a custom post type?  I need it to be made available on all posts for that `custom post type` is this possible?  So will be in the format:  `/members/{post-slug}/patents/`

Comment: use `add_rewrite_endpoint` to add an endpoint.

Comment: Ok, sorry, forgot to mention that I am already using that function within the `init` action, it is not working like a directory structure, instead it is only displaying the include when I browse to: `/members/john-doe/?patents`, but I need it to load on:  `/members/john-doe/patents/`, how?

Comment: It is also working on any post type, even regular posts.  I want it to only work for the `team_member` post type only.  Figured using `ep_mask` was the way to do this.

Comment: I don't think you can set `public` to `false`, it has to be publicly queryable. If you don't want it visible unless the endpoint is present, you'll have to hook something like `parse_query` and redirect those requests or make them 404. You can also remove `ep_mask`, it will default to `EP_PERMALINK`.

Comment: So, there is no way to set an endpoint for a specific custom post type than?  It must be on all post types?  Seriously?  What is the point of `ep_mask` anyways.  In any case, how to change endpoint from `?patents` to just `patents`?

Comment: If you only need it for the one type, then you can use `add_rewrite_rule` instead. The endpoint mask determines what link types the endpoint rules are added to, a non-hierarchical singular permalink isn't further differentiated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it, thanks for the point in the right direction guys!

```
add_rewrite_rule('^members/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?', '^members/$matches[1]/?$matches[2]', 'top');
```